# Derivative of equation in which x has superscripts and subscripts

Tags: calculus

The question is the find the gradient of $f(x)$ for $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$, yet I'm unsure as to what the superscripts and subscripts of $x$ mean and how to use them in calculating derivatives.
$$f(x)=12x_1^4 + 25x_2^2-3x_1x_2x_3$$

Comment: when they say derivative, they mean gradient or grad. Please search this up, and in the future, use Mathjax code so we can see what you are saying

Comment: Superscripts are powers, subscripts denote different variables. You could write your equivalence as $$f(x,y,z) = 12x^{4} + 25y^{2} - 3xyz$$ The gradient is given by $$\nabla f = (\partial_{x}, \partial_{y}, \partial_{z})f = (48x^{3}-3yz, 50y-3xz, -3xy)$$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Many thanks Mattos.